# Is it OK to publish or reverse engineer the PageDown + MathJax integration code?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, open-source

The [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) [sites](https://mathoverflow.net/) have a nice [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) + [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) integration.

It seems mostly based on [this Apache 2-licensed code](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/transfer/mathjax/mathjax-editing.js) by MathJax developer [David Cervone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502334/davide-cervone) with [some minor updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228558/let-pagedown-and-mathjax-work-together#comment17371250_11231030) to work around an IE bug and issues with backticks.

[Several people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228558/let-pagedown-and-mathjax-work-together) would like to do the same style of integration on their own sites.

Thus, my questions:

1. Can someone on the Stack Exchange team publish/open-source the latest non-minified mathjax-editing.en.js file?
2. If nobody is willing to do #1, can I unminify the [latest minified mathjax-editing.en.js](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=1186ac40edadand) and publish it (e.g. as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/))? [This is similar to what StackOverflow did with the WMD editor](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/).

Comment: It is unminified [here](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=1186ac40edadand) but I don't know the answer to the license so I'm not sure if you can use that.

Comment: To be 100% safe I'd recommend **NOT** doing #2 and patiently wait for #1 to happen. Publishing somebody else's code based on assumptions that it *probably* is also Apache 2.0 is a *very* risky feat.

Comment: The unminified version at http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js now shows an MIT License at the top.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have published a GIST for the Pagedown + MathJax integration under the MIT license.

https://gist.github.com/gdalgas/a652bce3a173ddc59f66

Feel free to do with it what you will!